# Where should I submit feature requests for Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a few requests that I would like to submit and track. What is the right way to submit those?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7689/where-should-i-submit-feature-requests-for-gazebo?/) by [iandanforth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1053/iandanforth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you should create an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues) and mark it as a feature request.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-12-14**:
or mark as enhancement